# Equations in right-to-left languages

Tags: mathematics

Is there an historical tradition in languages read right-to-left (Arabic, Hebrew, Urdu, etc.)
to display mathematical equations in some right-to-left form?
So, instead of
$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$
perhaps swapping expressions across the equals-sign,
$$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} = x$$
or even more thorough reversal inside expressions, e.g.,
$$\frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} \pm -b}{2a}= x$$
?

Comment: See [Typesetting Right-to-Left math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20666/typesetting-right-to-left-math) on TeX SE and references there.